# Sharefile API List all Users with access to Folder

Tags: sharefile

With the Sharefile API, is there a way to list all users who have access to a certain folder given a folder ID? Or given a user ID, is there a way to list the folders they have access to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the list of users that have access to some `folderId` (this is with the C# SDK, other SDKs should be similar):

```
string folderId;
ShareFileClient client;
...
var acls = await client.AccessControls.GetByItem(client.Items.GetEntityUriFromId(folderId)).ExecuteAsync();
foreach (var acl in acls.Feed)
{
    var user = acl.Principal;
    ...
}
```

I don't think the inverse is possible (getting a list of folders a particular user has access to).